# Grouping the nodes based on the taxonomy terms

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

A specific taxonomy page should display its description as well as the grouped teasers of the pages with the other taxonomy terms.
For example: An article (Article1) is having 2 taxonomy terms : Accounting, Finance. Another article (Article2) has 2 taxonomy terms: Accounting, Money.

My output **when I see the Accounting term page** (Example: http://www.myexample.com/group/accounting), the page output will contain the Accounting term description and the grouping of the remaining Taxonomy terms that the articles are linked to.

**Finance**

- Article 1
- Article x
- 

**Money**

- Article 2
- Article y
- 

I need a little customization here by grouping the articles with the remaining Taxonomy terms. I tried Views with Taxonomy Display and Taxonomy Views Integrator. But, couldn't organize the output.

Is there a way to alter the output of the 3 different taxonomy terms using Views?

Answer (score 0):

**Create a view add two fields:**

1. Node title
2. Taxonomy Term

**Follow these steps :**

1. Taxonomy Term" field to "Exclude from display
2. Set format = unformatted list in Format section
3. Set group Field as taxonomy term

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I tried the way as your post. But, as the Taxonomy terms are the group fields, it is grouping all the terms  associated with that page.

Comment: you can add filter on taxonomy term which term you want exclude

Comment: I edited the question. Please check the question and suggest changes if I can edit the view output using custom module.